# Agriculture shapefiles and additional GIS data for Australia

Tags: geospatial, australia, agriculture

I am searching for agriculture shapefiles and additional GIS data for Australia to save them in a PostGIS database.

More specific I need these data for mountains and their paths, climatic zones etc.

Can someone help me and give me some links where I am able to find these valid data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the links that might be what you are looking for but I'd google it if these were not what you are looking for:

http://www.diva-gis.org/Data

http://www.agriculture.gov.au/abares/data